# Parse.com receive JSON array from cloud clode function

Tags: android, json, arraylist, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to run my custom cloud code function from my Android app. I feel like it's something weird and I think that's not sufficiently documented in the guides of the platform.

Please help me, I am loosing way too much time over this!

The custom cloud code function returns an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "status":false,
      "usr":{  
         "URL":"a string",
         "__type":"Object",
         "blacklisted":false,
         "className":"_User",
         "createdAt":"2015-09-28T08:22:09.266Z",
         "description":"a string",
         "email":"a string",
         "emailVerified":true,
         "facebookId":"a string",
         "first_name":"a string",
         "gender":"male",
         "last_name":"a string",
         "name":"Filippo",
         "objectId":"a string",
         "updatedAt":"2015-09-28T12:58:31.455Z",
         "username":"a string"
      }
   }
   // Some other objects...
]
```

Now I'm trying to call the cloud code function from Android client with this:

```
final HashMap<String, ParseObject> params = new HashMap<String, ParseObject>();
    ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getConversations", params, new FunctionCallback<ArrayList<JSONObject>>() {
        @Override
        public void done(final ArrayList<JSONObject> results, ParseException e) {
            myAdapter = new InboxAdapter(getActivity(), results);
            listview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        } 
}
```

I get some strange behavior though, since using `ArrayList<JSONObject>` as generic for the callback won't allow me to populate an adapter, which keeps returning `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject` in the `getItem()` method

```
private ArrayList<JSONObject> list;
private Context ctx;

public InboxAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<JSONObject> s) {
    ctx = c;
    list = s;
}
/* All other methods */
@Override
public JSONObject getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position); // Gives exception!
}
```

I find it really strange since it's an ArrayList of `JSONObject`s and shouldn't care about maps and so on.
Also trying to use `new FunctionCallback<JSONArray>() {}` bounces me back, because it requires an arraylist! (and to be honest I didn't figure out why).

So what should I do in order to handle such a response from the Android side? Is there something I have to do in order to correctly parse the results?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hi can you modify your getConversations() written in cloud..Pass a Json Object in response.success...Here is a working example where test is your getConversations() function :-

```
 Parse.Cloud.define("test", function(request, response) {

    var text = "hello world";

  var jsonObject = {
    "answer": text
  };

  response.success(jsonObject);
});
```

Then call it and get values from android like this :-

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("test", null, new FunctionCallback< Map<String, Object> >() {
        public void done(Map<String, Object> mapObject, ParseException e) {
          if (e == null){   
            Toast.makeText(appContext, mapObject.get("answer").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          } 
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried it and I can can confirm that's the correct approach to handle json objects when getting a response, they have to be considered as Maps instead of JSONObjects. Thank you.